# How to show and hide the other item using the nz-radio-group in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Here's the code:

***list.component.html***

```html
   <nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                  <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
                  <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
                </nz-radio-group>
 <div>
              <textarea nz-input class="remarks-textarea" type="text" name="otherRemark" formControlName="remark" [(ngModel)]="otherRemark"
                [nzAutosize]="{ minRows: 3, maxRows: 3 }"></textarea>
            </div>
```

how to `show` the `div` which it has a `textarea`, it will show when in `radio button` select the `failed` and it will `hide` when it clicked the `passed`.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below image which has all formcontrol and (ngModelChange).

[image]

I think there is some issue with initialization. If you can elaborate more about your code that can help you to check further.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may be try to add *ngIf condition on div

`<div *ngIf="radioValue === 'failed'">`

[image]

Comment: ```ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: [object Object]'. Current value: 'model: undefined'.```

Comment: also did you remove the ``` (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)``` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use like bellow example:

HTML:

```html
<form [formGroup]="radioForm">
 <nz-radio-group formControlName="radiostatus" [(ngModel)]="radioValue" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStatus($event)">
                  <label nz-radio nzValue="passed">Passed</label>
                  <label nz-radio nzValue="failed">Failed</label>
                </nz-radio-group>
 <div *ngIf="radioValue === 'failed'">
              <textarea nz-input class="remarks-textarea" type="text" name="otherRemark" formControlName="remark" [(ngModel)]="otherRemark"
                [nzAutosize]="{ minRows: 3, maxRows: 3 }"></textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

Component ts:

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  radioForm = new FormGroup({
    radiostatus: new FormControl(''),
    remark:  new FormControl('')
  });

  onChangeStatus($event){
    console.log($event);
  }
}
```

Also you could use like `[hidden]="radioValue !== 'failed'"` instead of `*ngIf="radioValue === 'failed'"`

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-gqlcdw?file=src/app/app.component.html)